# Stripe payment split - how to implement?

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I am working on an app that will allow friends to split the cost of a service among themselves. I am wondering if

a) this is possible via Stripe

b) is there any working example of this / code that I can look at?

c) any security issues that arise specifically from this implementation

Thanks!

Comment: would this answer suffice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666338/split-payments-between-two-people-accounts ?

Comment: @RichardJordan that's different. I am looking for group of friends paying for a service, all 'pitching in'